# UnexpectedValueException Could not parse version constraint when trying to instal laravelcollective

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravelcollective

I am new to laravel and I am trying to install *laravelcollective*. I am just following to documentation [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) and I am using this from my project directory:

`composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"`

Unfortunately, immediately after I press ented I get the following error :

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Could not parse version constraint :5.4.0: Invalid version string ":5.4.0"

I just don't know how to troubleshoot this. I didn't find much on google and this combined with my lack of experience with laravel leaves me stuck.

Can someone help?

Comment: Use : `composer require "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"`

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package 5.4.* at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your
   minimum-stability

Comment: What is the version of "laravel/framework" in composer.json ?

Comment: it is version "5.4.*"

Comment: You can add it manually in `composer.json` then use `composer update`. Just add : `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",` under the row with `"laravel/framework":"5.4.*"`

Comment: thanks for suggesting this, it updated without errors. I will test it out now.

Comment: @ThomasRollet, this worked, thanks! If you want you can post it as na answer and then I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it manually in `composer.json` then use `composer update`.

Just add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",` under the row with `"laravel/framework":"5.4.*",`

Like this :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*", <-- Add this row
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
```

Comment: You should never run `composer update` without any arguments if you do not want to update **all** your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You should never run `composer update` without any arguments if you do not want to update **all** your dependencies.

In your case, the issue probably is that the `^` character is already interpreted by your shell before the argument is passed to Composer. This could possibly be solved by using single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.4.0'
```

When you used the `5.4.*` constraint as suggested in one of the comments above, you added a space after the colon which leads to Composer interpreting the version constraint as a package name. The right command would have been this:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"5.4.*"
```

Comment: So, do you think that by running composer update without arguments I might have ruined something else? By the way, I tried all variations and nothing was working.

Comment: The single quotes made it happen for me

Comment: Excellent call regarding the space after the colon. I had inadvertently added a space after the colon when inline-aliasing, e.g., `composer require "laravel/framework": "dev-pgsql-fixes as v5.8.35"`, and this error resulted.

Answer (score 2):

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html ^5.4.0"
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using Laravel 5.7 and kept getting an error when trying to install the Laravel collective.

You can use this command without specifying any version:

```
composer require 'laravelcollective/html'
```

It worked for me. :)