# why i do get an error on laravel-5 installation?

Tags: php, laravel-5, installation, frameworks, backend

i getting this error on lavarel installation by composer-project,do you have any ideia how to solve?

> Could not parse version constraint /var/www/html/my_blog1: Invalid version
> string "/var/www/html/my_blog1"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not parse version constraint ~x.x: Invalid version string "~x.x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242924/could-not-parse-version-constraint-x-x-invalid-version-string-x-x)

Comment: actually,it didn't

Comment: then have a look at this one. You just need to make sure the version string is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268095/unexpectedvalueexception-could-not-parse-version-constraint-when-trying-to-insta

Comment: so,i added the composer.json file schema from this source
https://getcomposer.org/schema.json
and i couldn't find the row on the last post on the code